# jQuery mobile: Why does .bind() work but not addEventListener?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

Working with jQuery mobile, I am trying to register a click event handler on a simple checkbox that looks like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb" />
<label for="cb">I am a checkbox</label>
```

Adding the click event handler using jQuery works:

```js
$("#cb").bind("click", function(){...});
```

Event handlers added using traditional DOM methods are not called:

```js
document.getElementById("cb").addEventListener("click", function(){...});
```

Big question is why? any ideas?

p.s. I have similar problems with event handlers for "pageinit" and "pagebeforeshow", which can just be received when added through "bind". aren't these events fired as DOM events?

**[edit]**

Here is a complete testcase ([link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5MN2/)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#cb").bind("click", function(){alert("Clicked by jquery")});
            document.getElementById("cb").addEventListener("click", function(){alert("Clicked by DOM")});
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb" />
    <label for="cb">I am a checkbox</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**[edit 2]**

answering my own question: The click doesn't seem to come through when using the jquery mobile css files, probably because it shows the label over the checkbox. Without using the CSS, everything works as expected.

**[edit 3]**

answering my own second question, why i can't catch "pageinit" and other custom events via addEventListener: it is a [jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11047).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know addEventListener takes three parameters and not 2 only, eg :

```
/**
* in DHTML
* @param {String} type
* @param {Function} listener
* @param {Boolean} [useCapture]
*/
window.addEventListener = function(type,listener,useCapture) {};
```

Or

```
/**
* in DOMEvents
* @param {String} type
* @param {EventListener|Function} listener
* @param {Boolean} [useCapture]
*/
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type,listener,useCapture) {};
```

Comment: useCapture is already optional for quite a while (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)), so that can't be it. thanks though!